# Two table Addition

Tags: sqlite

```
 `ForgeRock Table`

id      status  rank    Name            description
---------------------------------------------------------
1        0      111      jax              music
2        0      234      kevin              art 
3        0      456      DJ              music

 `ForgeRock1 Table`

id      status  rank    Name            description
---------------------------------------------------------
1        1      111      jax              swim
2        1      234      kevin             tennis 
4        0      456      Devil             football
```

Expected Result

```
id      status  rank    Name            description
---------------------------------------------------------
1        1      111      jax               swim
2        1      234      kevin             tennis 
3        0      456      DJ                music
4        0      456      Devil             football
```

If status field changes to 1 then take record corresponding to status=1 and remaining all records.

Query:

```
 Select * from ForgeRock
     Union
 Select * from ForgeRock1
```

Comment: Do you have any relationship b/w the tables?

Comment: Yes both tables are stored in different databases.If "status" field of any record changed to "1" then only change "description" field.

Comment: And Update both Tables With Expected Result (i.e Updated Tables)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using `Inner JOIN` and `UNION`. Query below does a `Inner join` and so only matched record (1,2) comes up and based on the status value b/w the table we are deciding which value to pick up using a `CASE` statement. You can read more about `JOINS/CASE expression` in `SqlLite` document.

```
 Select f1.id,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.status else f2.status end as Status,
      f1.rank,
      f1.Name,
      case when f1.status = 1 then f1.description else f2.description end as description
      from ForgeRock f1
 inner join ForgeRock1 f2 on f1.id = f2.id 

     union all

 Select id,
      Status,
      rank,
      Name,
      description 
      from ForgeRock
   where id not in (select distinct id from ForgeRock1)

union all

 Select id,
      Status,
      rank,
      Name,
      description 
      from ForgeRock1
   where id not in (select distinct id from ForgeRock)
```